# Assign variable that contains NA values using rep()

Tags: r

I was checking outlier using residuals after model fitting. I wanted to create a new column for the residuals to match with my response variables. However, the original response variables contains missing value (`NA`). R returns the error message

> "Supplied 481 items to be assigned to 512 items of column 'ch4_p_h_residual'. If you wish to 'recycle' the RHS please use rep() to make this intent clear to readers of your code."

```
fit_all <- lmer(ch4_p_h ~ NOP *Cottonseed * Hour + 
                 (1|Period) + (1|Cow) + (1|Breed),
                df_lsd)

plot_redres(fit_all, "std_cond")
anova(fit_all)

residual_diagnoise(fit_all)
df_lsd[, ch4_p_h_residual := residuals(fit_all)]
```

I would like to know where to add the `rep()` in my code to correctly assign the residual to the corresponding response variable.

Comment: I don't think you want to use `rep()`.  I think you want to assign the values in `residuals(fit_all)` to the corresponding rows in `df_lsd`.   Your example is not reproducible (we have no data), so it is difficult to advise you correctly on how to proceed.

Answer (score 1):

Use `na.reduce` instead of the default `na.omit`. It pads the residuals to the original number of observations in the data.frame.

```
library(lme4)
DF <- sleepstudy
DF[1, "Reaction"] <- NA

fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), DF)

DF$res <- residuals(fm1)
#Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, res, value = c(`2` = -15.8064403297435,  : 
#  replacement has 179 rows, data has 180

fm1 <- lmer(Reaction ~ Days + (Days | Subject), DF, na.action = na.exclude)

DF$res <- residuals(fm1)
#works
```